# How to get Business Listed in Google, Yahoo and Bing

Tags: ruby, google-places-api, bing-api, yahoo-api

I am currently working on an application which requires to find that whether the Business is listed and also claimed in Google, Bing and Yahoo (Something like http://getlisted.org) when a user enters his business name and zipcode. I am using google places API for checking for listed in google, Also Yahoo local API for listed in yahoo. But not able to determine how to use the Bing portal API for doing the same.Also how to get any conclusion about the Business is claimed in all three.
Any help would be great.Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bingmaps/thread/94416ac9-4126-4021-bc8f-a109316d95fd ?